# System.getProperty can't read jnlp - resources since java 7 - Could this be because of an unsigned JNLP-File

Tags: java, java-7, java-web-start, jnlp, sign

I try to repear a Java Web Starter Application witch is broken since Java 7. It worked befor. 
All the Jar Files are signed.

I try to get the information of the resource-tag from my jnlp-file.

I use System.getProperty but it returns null.

I searched for a while but I didn't find an answer to the following Questions:

1. Do I have to sign the JNLP-File to be allowed to get the resources tag?
2. If I do, how can I do this? I read that I have to put it in the same jar like the start Class, but I didn't find a good instruction how to do this.
3. I read, that the jnlp must be named APPLICATION.JNLP and musst be in the JNLP-INF folder. Is this necessary? There has this folder to be? Can he be anythere?
4. I read the releaselog from oracle what is new in Java 7. I didn't found a change of the System.getProperty and the in this function used SecurityManager. Am I right, that this didn't change?

Here is the I think important Part of the Code:

Ok So this is the line i try to get one of the Resource-tag:

```
String strApiPath = System.getProperty("apipath");
System.out.println(strApiPath);
```

strApiPath is null.

The resources part of the jnlp looks like:

```xml
<resources> 

    <j2se version="1.5+" initial-heap-size="64m" max-heap-size="512m"/>


    <jar href="dist/pathtool-2.jar"/>
   <jar href="jars/resources.jar"/>
    <jar href="jars/reporting-api-javaclient.jar"/> 

    <jar href="jars/commons-collections-3.2.jar"/>
    <jar href="jars/colt.jar"/>
    <jar href="jars/jdom.jar"/>


    <jar href="jars/ptjung1.7.jar"/>

    <jar href="jars/commons-configuration-1.2.jar"/>
    <jar href="jars/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar"/>
    <jar href="jars/commons-lang-2.1.jar"/> 

    <jar href="jars/commons-logging-1.1.jar"/>
    <jar href="jars/commons-logging-api-1.1.jar"/>
    <jar href="jars/commons-codec-1.3.jar"/>

    <jar href="jars/jnlp.jar"/>


    <!-- http or https -->
    <property name="protocol" value="http"/> 
    <!-- Domainname or ip -->
    <property name="host" value="localhost"/>
    <property name="port" value="8080"/>
    <property name="proxyactive" value="false"/>
    <property name="proxyhost" value="false"/>
    <property name="proxyport" value="false"/>
    <property name="webuser" value="dummy"/>
    <property name="webpwd" value="dummy"/>
    <property name="apipath" value="../../api_basic"/> 
    <property name="user" value="123"/> 
    <property name="psw" value="123"/> 
    <property name="datasource" value="eval"/>

  </resources>
```

Comment: maybe a little code where you are stuck will help us all solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Starting in java7 update51 there are new requirements for web start applications.

- All the jars need to signed (not with self-signed cert) with a certificate
- The manifest file needs to be updated - see [this link](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/manifest.html)

Some of the output is warnings but the 'permissions' tag is the required tag.

What kinds of error are you getting?

Comment: Hey,yes we have a certificate and I updated all the manifestfiles. I don't get a error or a warning or anything else in the console. The getProperty just returns null and I can't figure out why :(